# How many Chinese Postman routes are needed to cover a mixed multigraph?

Tags: graph-theory

In short: How many Chinese Postman open paths are needed to cover a mixed multigraph?

---

The Chinese Postman problem asks: What is the circuit that visits every edge at least once? For a graph with a Euler circuit it's obviously that circuit. For a graph without a Euler circuit, some backtracking may be needed.

There's also the open CPP where we don't require the path to start and end at the same point.  Likewise, open Euler path is a solution.

All the literature that I've found discusses strongly connected graphs where every node can be reached from every other node. I want to know how many open CPP paths are needed to visit every edge of a mixed multigraph. That is, the graph has both directed and undirected edges. The graph may also have loops and multiple edges between points.

Answer (score 0):

My thinking so far:

I can convert a multigraph into directed acyclic graphs of it's strongly connected components with any algorithm. (There may be more than one DAG.) We know that it'll be DAGs because if there were undirected edges, those would be in a component. And if there was a cycle, it would be in a component.

First count one for each node that has no edges in or out. Those are strongly connected components full of edges and a single path there will suffice. Remove those nodes and count one for each.

Now start at a random node in our DAGs that has no inward path (a root), and travel a random path to a node with no outward paths (a leaf). Count one and then remove all the edges of the path except the ones that split the DAG into two DAGs. Repeat until all edges are gone.

The final count is the number of open CPP paths needed to visit each edge.

I don't know if this answer if this is correct nor if it's a good solution. I especially don't like the conditional removal of edges, which seems pretty messy to me.